# How to make 3 clickable area on a button in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm new in objective-C and I've create a project that use a button to change some elements from my view. I would like  that depending on what part of the button I click, it displays different elements than previous. 
For exemple when I click on the left area from button a red circle appears and when I click in the middle, it's the blue circle that appears and in the right area it's a green circle. 
I tried searching on google and stackoverflow but I have trouble understanding how the selector used in this case. Could someone help me?

PS: Sorry for the mistakes, my English is not very good

Comment: What about detecting where the user clicked, or using a custom item with in back end 3 buttons? What have you tried?

Comment: maybe you are looking for `UISegmentedControl`?

Comment: Larme : It's for the school. My teacher wants us to use with one button and color of the circle depends on witch part I click. The only clue he gave it's that I have to use selector. I've already use the selector when I had created a button by the code in other project. But here I don't understood how to use the selector to selct a part of the button.

Comment: RolandasR: I never came across this method in my research. Thank you I 'll dig it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I help you.

First you need the create the small custom view programmatically or through the xib or storyboard

```
   UIView *viewButton = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake ( 100, 100, 300, 300)];

   [self.view addSubView:viewButton];
```

Then Create the 3 buttons inside the viewButton

```
 //First Button

 UIButton *buttonLeftRed = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
           OR
 UIButton *buttonLeftRed = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
 buttonLeftRed.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
 buttonLeftRed.tag = 1;
 [buttonLeftRed setTitle:@"Red" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [buttonLeftRed addTarget:self 
       action:@selector(actionPressMeOne:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [viewButton addSubview:buttonLeftRed];


 //Second Button

 UIButton *buttonMiddleBlue = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
           OR
 UIButton *buttonMiddleBlue = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
 buttonMiddleBlue.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 100, 100);
 buttonMiddleBlue.tag = 2;
 [buttonMiddleBlue setTitle:@"Blue" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [buttonMiddleBlue addTarget:self 
       action:@selector(actionPressMeSecond:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [viewButton addSubview:buttonMiddleBlue];


 //Third Button

 UIButton *buttonRightGreen = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
           OR
 UIButton *buttonRightGreen = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
 buttonRightGreen.frame = CGRectMake(200, 0, 100, 100);
 buttonRightGreen.tag = 3;
 [buttonRightGreen setTitle:@"Blue" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [buttonRightGreen addTarget:self 
       action:@selector(actionPressMeThird:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [viewButton addSubview:buttonRightGreen];    


If you want to change circle button, you have to import the Quartzcore Framework
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

 #pragma mark - UIButton Action Methods

 //First
 - (void)actionPressMeOne:(UIButton *)sender 
 {
     NSLog(@"Pressed Button Tag is - %@",sender.tag);
     UIButton *button = sender;
    //Then do whatever you want to do here
    //half of the width
     button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width/2.0f;
     button.layer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
     button.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;
     button.clipsToBounds = YES;
     [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
 }

 //Second
 - (void)actionPressMeSecond:(UIButton *)sender 
 {
     NSLog(@"Pressed Button Tag is - %@",sender.tag);
     UIButton *buttonTwo = sender;
    //Then do whatever you want to do here
    //half of the width
     buttonTwo.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width/2.0f;
     buttonTwo.layer.borderColor=[UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
     buttonTwo.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;
     buttonTwo.clipsToBounds = YES;
     [buttonTwo setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
 }    

 //Third
 - (void)actionPressMeThird:(UIButton *)sender 
 {
     NSLog(@"Pressed Button Tag is - %@",sender.tag);
     UIButton *buttonThree = sender;
    //Then do whatever you want to do here
    //half of the width
     buttonThree.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width/2.0f;
     buttonThree.layer.borderColor=[UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
     buttonThree.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;
     buttonThree.clipsToBounds = YES;
     [buttonThree setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
 }
```

Thank You:-)

Comment: Your solution is interesting but  but I think at the end I will use the RolandasR's solution. It is the least complicated for me and I think my teacher will validate anyway.
I tick your answer, it can be used for other and maybe an other time for me.
Thanks for your help.